# Defining buildURL depending on what properties have changed

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I would like to redefine my buildURL depending on what properties changed on the same model. For example, if the status changed, I would like to PUT to a certain route, and if the subuser changed, I would like to PUT to another route.

Example :

```
this.store.find('conversation', conv.id).then(function(conversation){
    conversation.set('status', 'opened');
    conversation.save();                    
});
```

This would use a certain PUT route and this :

```
this.store.find('conversation', this.get('selectedConv').id).then(function(conversation){
    conversation.set('subuser', subuser);
    conversation.set('url', subuser.get('email'));
    conversation.save();
});
```

And this would use another PUT route even tho the changes are made on the same model. This is all happening in a controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to customize your `conversation` adapter, specifically the `urlForUpdateRecord` method.

The original method [looks](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/v1.0.0-beta.19.1/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/build-url-mixin.js#L184) like this:

```
urlForUpdateRecord: function(id, modelName, snapshot) {
  return this._buildURL(modelName, id);
},
```

In this method, you need to examine the snapshot and adjust the URL accordingly.

The latest version of Ember Data has introduced the [changedAttributes](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.Snapshot.html#method_changedAttributes) property. This seems to be what you need.

Good luck!